# How to add a second row of toolbar using Xamarin.Mac

Tags: c#, macos, xamarin

I have a split window controller with sidebar as follows:

[Split Window Controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2RP6e.png)

I want to be able to click on the pencil icon in the toolbar and another row of toolbar shows up, like the Preview app:

[second row of toolbar in Preview app](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YfCwU.png)

Is there a straight forward way to do this via Xcode and I'm missing something simple?

I tried adding two toolbars in the one window but that did nothing. I would really appreciate some help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following tutorial that pretty much explains it in detail:

https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/xamarin-docs/blob/live/docs/mac/platform/introduction-to-macos-sierra/modern-cocoa-apps.md

Under "Using Accessory View Controllers".

After days of searching I finally found the right resources (that's how its always like with Xamarin Mac lol)